# Help with formulating a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

I have the following linear programming problem I would like to be verified:

[image]

I have sketched the problem in the following picture:

[image]

Here is my attempted solution:

I figured that I have ten variables (corresponding to the colored lines, between each building): $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{10}$ which are the amounts (in tons) of raw materials from **Source 1 --> Plant A, Source 1 --> Plant B, Source 2 --> Plant A, Source 2 --> Plant B, Plant A --> Market 1, Plant A --> Market 2, ............, Plant B --> Market 3**.

The formulation I get is the following:

$$\text{minimize}\;\;\; 1x_1 + 1.5x_2 + 2x_3 + 1.5x_4 + 4x_5 + 2x_6 + 1x_7 + 3x_8 + 4x_9 + 2x_{10}$$
$$\text{subject to}\;\;\;x_1 + x_2 = 10$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x_3 + x_4 = 15$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x_5 + x_8 = 8$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x_6 + x_9 = 14$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x_7 + x_{10} = 3$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, \cdots, x_{10} \ge 0.$$

I would appreciate if someone could verify the correctness of my answer :) Thank you for any help!

Comment: It looks correct and well presented to me. You might consider to reduce the number of variables. Example: $x_8 = 8 - x_5$. You put the source and market constraints as equalities. In real situations, they might be inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term $1x_9$ is wrong in the minimisation, it should be $4x_9$. Rest is correct. Proceed further.

**ADDED** Now that you have edited it, it is corret.

Comment: +1 @Shobhit Thank you :) Yes I edited it after you notified me:) thnx about that :)

Comment: No problem @jjepsuomi

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks correct although I would advise you for the sake of clarity to introduce new variables separately for markets, plants and sources (so for instance $x_i$ for the sources $y_i$ for the plants etc.). Also, instead of writing equality signs in some of the constraints, it might be neater to write inequality signs,(for instance, the 3 market centers require... actually means *at least*) although it doesn't really matter for the outcome and your answer would also be considered correct. Good job :-)

Comment: +1 @rbm thank you for your help :) I will keep your advice in my mind :) thnx :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi No problem :)